# Assembly analysis problem

Tags: assembly, gdb

```
(gdb) l main
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   
3   int main(void)
4   {
5       int i = 6;
6       printf("%d",sizeof(unsigned short));
7       return 0;
8   }
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x0000000000400498 <main+0>:    push   %rbp
0x0000000000400499 <main+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x000000000040049c <main+4>:    sub    $0x10,%rsp
0x00000000004004a0 <main+8>:    movl   $0x6,-0x4(%rbp)
0x00000000004004a7 <main+15>:   mov    $0x2,%esi
0x00000000004004ac <main+20>:   mov    $0x4005c8,%edi
0x00000000004004b1 <main+25>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x00000000004004b6 <main+30>:   callq  0x400398 <printf@plt>
0x00000000004004bb <main+35>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x00000000004004c0 <main+40>:   leaveq 
0x00000000004004c1 <main+41>:   retq
```

I have two doubts:

1. For `int i = 6`,only `4` bytes is needed,why `16` bytes allocated?
2. some functions use stack to pass parameters(by `push xxx`),but why `printf` uses `esi` and `edi` to do this ?

**UPDATE**

seems `printf` is not fetching from `esi` and `edi`:

```
(gdb) disas printf
Dump of assembler code for function printf@plt:
0x0000000000400398 <printf@plt+0>:  jmpq   *0x2004c2(%rip)        # 0x600860 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+24>
0x000000000040039e <printf@plt+6>:  pushq  $0x0
0x00000000004003a3 <printf@plt+11>: jmpq   0x400388
```

Answer (score 3):

> why 16 bytes

Because [x86_64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) requires that the stack be 16-byte aligned before the call instruction

> why printf uses esi and edi

Because [x86_64 ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) specifies that (first 6) integer parameters be passed in `rdi`, `rsi`,  `rdx`, `rcx`, `r8` and `r9` registers.

Comment: Thanks for 16-byte alignment answer.But seems why printf uses esi and edi is not answered?How do functions know where to get parameters if there're more than 1 branches?

Comment: In that case branching will be done first and parameters are loaded in to registers once branching is done ..

Comment: @Zimbabao ,I mean how sub_function knows where to fetch parameters?

Comment: how can I get the alignment size and architectural size in assembly?

Answer (score 1):

1. It should be 4 bytes for int, 8 bytes for stack frame pointer(rbp 64 bit register) and 4 bytes for return value (in stack).
2. I've not really witnessed it(i'm oldschool :P), but i've heard it's a new way to push values. It's supposed to be faster by directly storing values to stack.

Comment: For 2,how do functions know where to get parameters if there're more than 1 branches?

Comment: For 1,should not the return address be 8 bytes,like `0x00000000004004ac`?

Comment: This answer is completely bogus. You may note that 16 bytes are reserved on stack *after* frame pointer has been pushed.

Comment: Employed Russian, this is exactly what happens in every program in this planet. The stack frame pointer is pushed first.

Comment: @soyrosp: Yes, but when its pushed esp is decreased (or increase in come archs) at the time pop and push instructions. You need not change is separately. And return address is pushed before pushing ebp. 16bytes reserved is after both return address and fp is pushed and @employed russian answered it above.

Comment: right Zimbabao, my bad on that, you really have to take a look at a debugger when discussing the stack :P difficult to see the layout in mind.